# R paste does not respect factor order

Tags: r, data.table, paste

I have a data set with two columns

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(x = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 25), y = rep(25:1, times = 4))
```

I specify the ordered levels of both columns as factors

```
DT$x <- factor(DT$x, levels = c("A","B","D","C"))
DT$y <- factor(DT$y, levels = 1:25)
```

When I paste them together, they do not paste in the order that I have specified in their levels.

```
DT[ , z := paste(DT$x, DT$y, sep = "-")]
```

I would expect the list to start with `A-1` but instead it begins with `A-25`. Because of the non-alphabetical order of `x`, I can't reorder using `setkey`, which would reorder the actual data inside `DT`.

How can I paste `x` and `y` together and have them respect the order of factors I have specified in `z`?

Comment: Do this to sort your `DT$y`: `DT <- DT[gtools::mixedorder(DT$y),]` And then run `DT[ , z := paste(DT$x, DT$y, sep = "-")]`

Comment: I just used numbers as a MWE @TheTime so they actually do end up being factors.

Comment: @TheTime no, I want `1` to be encoded as the first one. But the way the data is collected has `25` appearing first.